# How to split a matrix into sub-matrices using scala

Tags: scala

I'm wondering what the most correct way to do this in Scala is:

Id like to initialise a matrix like the following

```
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3
```

Then id like to split it into 4 blocks :

```
0 1 | 2 3
0 1 | 2 3
---------
0 1 | 2 3
0 1 | 2 3
```

To end up with 4 matrices:

```
0 1   2 3   0 1   2 3
0 1   2 3   0 1   2 3
```

I can think of a few ways to do it with loops etc, but are there more functional ways to do it using scala's list methods?

Cheers
NFV

Comment: How are you representing your matrix?

Comment: Is the size of the original matrix fixed?  Or will it vary, but always be a multiple of 2 along each axis?

Comment: Try working with `Seq` and it's method `grouped(size:Int)` and see what you can come up with.. come back with some code if you're having trouble, and see if we can help refine your approach.

Comment: @MyseriousDan - Im new to scala so open to suggestions

Comment: @RichardSitze The size can be assumed to be square and even

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the matrix as a list of lists.

```
scala> val matrix = List(List(0,1,2,3),List(4,5,6,7), List(8,9,10,11),List(11,12,13,14))
matrix: List[List[Int]] = List(List(0, 1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6, 7), List(8, 9, 10, 11), List(11, 12, 13, 14))
```

Group the rows with `grouped` and match each group to extract the first half and the second half using `take` and `takeRight`

```
scala> matrix.grouped(2).flatMap(xs => xs match {
     | case x: List[List[Int]] => List(x.head.take(2) ::: x.last.take(2), List(x.head.takeRight(2) ::: x.last.takeRight(2)))
     | })
res0: Iterator[List[Any]] = non-empty iterator


scala> res0.toList
res1: List[List[Any]] = List(List(0, 1, 4, 5), List(List(2, 3, 6, 7)), List(8, 9, 11, 12), List(List(10, 11, 13, 14)))
```

This will work on square matrices and you'll have to do some more work for matrices of other sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Brian, using your code i came up with a way to apply it to a matrix of any size

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a square matrix with a size evenly divisible by 2:

```
scala> val size = 4
size: Int = 4

scala> val matrix = List.fill(size)(List.range(0,size))
matrix: List[List[Int]] = List(List(0, 1, 2, 3), List(0, 1, 2, 3), List(0, 1, 2, 3), List(0, 1, 2, 3))

scala> matrix.map(_.grouped(size/2).toList).grouped(size/2).map(_.transpose).reduce(_ ++ _)
res0: List[List[List[Int]]] = List(List(List(0, 1), List(0, 1)), List(List(2, 3), List(2, 3)), List(List(0, 1), List(0, 1)), List(List(2, 3), List(2, 3)))
```